# How to implement loop on fetched data though group by clause in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to implement loop on fetch data but it is giving error that property does not exist.

```
$SaleOrderProducts = SaleOrderProducts::where('sale_order_id', $id)->get()->groupBy('purchase_order_product.products.id');
```

I tried this

```
foreach($SaleOrderProducts as $product)

{
  return $product->products->id;
}
```

When I just return `$products`

```
foreach($SaleOrderProducts as $product)

{
  return $product;
}
```

then it returns data in this format

```
[{"id":6,"sale_order_id":2,"product_id":5,"purchase_order_product_id":5,"qty_taken":75,"created_at":"2020-01-31 19:04:05","updated_at":"2020-01-31 22:33:41","purchase_order_product":{"id":5,"purchase_order_id":1,"product_id":5,"measurement_unit":"Cartons","expiry_date":"2020-02-01","created_at":"2020-01-31 19:02:03","updated_at":"2020-01-31 22:33:41","status":1,"initial_qty":454,"on_hand_qty":454,"free_qty":389,"orignal_qty":454,"location":null,"products":{"id":5,"name":"Glass","customer_id":1,"product_type_id":1,"product_status_id":1,"code":"d23123","status":1,"description":"kkd","storage_charge_method":"Per Location","volume":4444554,"weight":545,"random_weight":"Yes","warning_threshold_duration":0,"expiry_threshold_duration":0,"low_stock_notification":"off","low_threshold_duration":null,"stock_selection_method":"Locaiton Efficiency Only","strict_stock_selection":"off","stock_sub_selection_method":"Minimise Storage"}}}]
```

Comment: where is `purchase_order_product` from? json field?

Comment: ```"purchase_order_product":{"id":5,"purchase_order_id":1,"product_id":5,"measurement_unit":"Cartons","expiry_date":"2020-02-01","created_at":"2020-01-31 19:02:03","updated_at":"2020-01-31 22:33:41","status":1,"initial_qty":454,"on_hand_qty":454,"free_qty":389,"orignal_qty":454,"location":null,```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code

```
foreach($SaleOrderProducts as $product)
{
  return current($product)->purchase_order_product->products->id;
}
```

Comment: giving this error ```ErrorException (E_NOTICE)
Trying to get property 'purchase_order_product' of non-object
```

Comment: added another another with the sample json given. please check. if you share result of $SaleOrderProducts will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Sample with the given json response

```
$product = json_decode('[{"id":6,"sale_order_id":2,"product_id":5,"purchase_order_product_id":5,"qty_taken":75,"created_at":"2020-01-31 19:04:05","updated_at":"2020-01-31 22:33:41","purchase_order_product":{"id":5,"purchase_order_id":1,"product_id":5,"measurement_unit":"Cartons","expiry_date":"2020-02-01","created_at":"2020-01-31 19:02:03","updated_at":"2020-01-31 22:33:41","status":1,"initial_qty":454,"on_hand_qty":454,"free_qty":389,"orignal_qty":454,"location":null,"products":{"id":5,"name":"Glass","customer_id":1,"product_type_id":1,"product_status_id":1,"code":"d23123","status":1,"description":"kkd","storage_charge_method":"Per Location","volume":4444554,"weight":545,"random_weight":"Yes","warning_threshold_duration":0,"expiry_threshold_duration":0,"low_stock_notification":"off","low_threshold_duration":null,"stock_selection_method":"Locaiton Efficiency Only","strict_stock_selection":"off","stock_sub_selection_method":"Minimise Storage"}}}]');

echo "<pre>";print_r(current($product)->purchase_order_product->products->id);
```

Comment: ```
json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given
```

Comment: what is the encoding you are using? what is the Operating system you are using?